# New instance of self in a click function

Tags: javascript

When I try a code that is structured as followed:

```
function foo(bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
    this.rec = function(e) {
        return function() {
            var elem = $('');
            var new_foo = new foo(elem);
        };
    };
    this.init = function() {
        this.bar.click(this.rec());
    };
}
var obj = new foo($(''));
```

I get TypeError: foo is not a constructor
I'm thinking that it has to do with scope, but I don't know if what I'm trying to do is even possible. Is there a way for me to create a new instance of the same class from within the click function that is also inside the same class? Or am I just going about this the wrong way?

Edit: as some pointed out i was replacing the function, but that was just a typo in this example, that doesn't happen in the final code where I'm getting the problem. But thank you for pointing it out, Im editing it now.

Comment: Probably has to do with the fact that you replace the foo function with the value of the foo function execution at the end of your code. Could you try replacing the last line with `var bar = new foo($(''));`

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> var foo = new foo($(''));
> ```

You're overwriting the `foo` constructor function with an instance of foo.

Don't do that. Use a different variable name.

Comment: You're right, my bad, this doesn't happen in my final code, I just wasn't thinking about it when I wrote this example.

Comment: note that using `var self = this;` in the beginning of `foo` function and `new self()` in `this.rec`, you would avoid this kind of problem